# What is a content selector in Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.0?

Tags: nexus

I was playing around with Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.0, trying to figure out how to pull off repository targets, when I came across content selectors. I am unable to find any documentation whatsoever on them, which I find odd.

What is a content selector, are they similar to repository targets, and how are they used? I am using Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.0.0-03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems they added the documentation about ContentSelector in the 3.1 release.

find the doc [here](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/admin.html#content-selectors)

Comment: latest documentation is here https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Configuration#Configuration-ContentSelectors : in a nutshell you define a Content Selector as a "filter" identifying a set of artifacts (e.g. all jars with a given groupId, like coordinate.groupId="bla" ) . Then you create a "privilege" associated to this Content Selector, for instance to allow only members of a group to edit the "bla" artifacts. It seems that the only use of Content Selectors is related to privileges.

Comment: Looks like the link got updated again: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-ContentSelectors

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering the same thing! Looks like there's a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NXBOOK-954) raised for documenting that.

I'm able to create a simple one (e.g. `asset.group=junit`) using [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html), based on the javadoc in the [unit test](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/b66425c9693b071c52f37357d4b9dadd9d383750/components/nexus-selector/src/test/java/org/sonatype/nexus/selector/SelectorTest.java) for Selectors, but I'm not sure how it's used. Maybe it will be a searchable field to find matching components?

I also found the following [article](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/05/11/migrating-to-nexus-repository-3-easy-peasy/) published last week which suggests that it will be available in 3.1:

> In addition 3.1 includes a number of other great features such as PyPi
>   support and Content Selectors. But I can tell more about that another
>   time – today we are going to look at migration.

Comment: Yes, I got to a similar stage. I think all we can do is wait and see, if someone else doesn't provide us information.